# How to manually build a django `HttpRequest`

Tags: python, django

I have the following in `requests`:

```
url = "http://hello.net"
res = requests.post(url, {'email':'hello@gmail.com'})
```

How would I convert this same request into a django `HttpRequest`? So far I have:

```
>>> from django.http import HttpRequest
>>> request = HttpRequest()
>>> request.method = 'POST'
>>> request.POST = {'email': 'hello@gmail.com'}
```

How would I then 'post to the url'? Additionally, is there any advantage of using a `HttpRequest` object over using the `requests` method?

Comment: What is the context? Are you testing? If so, use the django test client.

Comment: @wim I'd like to view the data of some jwt methods and see how I can validate them.

Comment: And how does Django fit into the picture?  It's very strange to try and use the Django request class to make a request directly.

Comment: It has a django backend, so I'd like to see how it's passing session data, etc.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You can't use a Django httprequest to make external requests.

Comment: Django uses [wsgi](https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/what.html).  It sounds like you just want a http client, in which case use requests or whatever.

Comment: @wim -- what would be the difference then in using the django `TestClient` and just using plain old `requests`?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is django backend, if you would like to see how it's passing session data, etc.
just refer this link

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/http/request/#HttpRequest